# How to load separate queries with same input using Dash?

Tags: plotly, plotly-dash, dashboard

I'm trying to build a Dash dashboard. I would like to display a DataTable, and for that get data from 2 sources. The first query is slow, so I would like to do it only when one of the inputs changes, and the other query I'd like to run continuously.

I've tried splitting them in 2 separate callbacks with similar inputs, but this fails. I think it's due to the 2nd callback already executing and not having input from the first yet, but not sure how to do it. I've tried creating a Store module to do this in.

Help would be much appreciated.

```
app = Dash(__name__)
app.index_string = layout.index_string
app.layout = layout.Column([
    layout.Row([
        layout.Column([
            html.Label("Input"),
            dcc.Input(id='user-input', value='ABC'),
        ]),
    ], padding=2),
    dash_table.DataTable(id='grid'),
    dcc.Store(id='heavy-data'),
    dcc.Interval(id='interval', interval=50_000)
])


@app.callback(
    Input('user-input', 'value'),
    Output('heavy-data', 'data'))
def get_heavy_data(user_input):
    heavy_data = create_heavy_data(user_input)

    return heavy_data.to_json(date_format='iso', orient='split')


@app.callback(
    Output('grid', 'data'),
    Output('grid', 'columns'),
    Input('heavy-data', 'data'),
    Input('user-input', 'value'),
    Trigger('interval', 'n_intervals'))
def get_all_data(heavy_data, user_input):
    light_data = create_light_data(user_input)
    data = light_data.merge(heavy_data, how='left')

    return [
        data.to_dict('records'),
        [{'id': i} for i in data.columns]
    ]



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your situation correctly, I think you would be best served by handling this situation with a single callback that performs different actions based on which component is modified by the user. I would remove the first callback completely and replace the second callback with one that follows this pattern.

I changed your `dcc.Store("heavy-data").data` from an Input to a State to prevent the newly updated data from triggering a second, unnecessary trip through the callback.

```py
@app.callback(
    Output('grid', 'data'),
    Output('grid', 'columns'),
    Output('heavy-data', 'data'),  # <--- Add Here/Combine to single callback
    Input('user-input', 'value'),
    Input('interval', 'n_intervals'),
    State('heavy-data', 'data'),  # State allows you to use the data without an update to it re-triggering this callback
)
def get_all_data(user_input, n_intervals, heavy_data):
    trigger_component_id = dash.callback_context.triggered[0]["prop_id"].split(".")[0]
    if trigger_component_id == 'user-input':  # only create new heavy data if user-input triggers the callback
        heavy_data = create_heavy_data(user_input)

    light_data = create_light_data(user_input)
    data = light_data.merge(heavy_data, how='left')

    return [
        data.to_dict('records'),
        [{'id': i} for i in data.columns],
        heavy_data
    ]
```

Comment: Very nice idea to split in the function by trigger reason! However when I use this the value that I receive from `heavy_data` is the `n_interval` value rather than the json that I return. If I change it from State to Input however it does work. Any idea why that fails?

Comment: I forgot to give the callback function an argument for the n_intervals input.  I made an edit to the code above.  Moved the interval component to be the second Input and kept heavy-data as a State.  This should bring in heavy-data as the appropriate data type.

Comment: Did this fix your problem?  Please mark the question answered if so to prevent others from investing time to assist when it's not required.